# How do I assign my array of int numbers with their proper String in my simple slot machine program?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I am having one of the most frustrating moments in my life (second semester coding challenge).
I am utilizing two lists to obtain three random numbers, and then I want those three random numbers to be assigned to their proper logo like a slot machine. However, my for loops are not behaving like I want them to... It is spitting out three results per random number.

`import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class LabProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

```
  final int numReels = 3;
  Random random = new Random(); 

  int[ ] symbols = new int[numReels];
  String [ ] logo = new String [numReels];
  
  
  for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; ++i) {
     symbols[ i ] = random.nextInt(5);
  //System.out.println(symbols[i]);
  }
  
  for (int k = 0; k < symbols.length; ++k)
     for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
     
     if (symbols[k] == 0) {
         logo[j] = "Cherry";
         
     }
     else if (symbols[k] == 1) {
         logo[j] = "7";
         
     }
     else if (symbols[k] == 2) {
         logo[j] = "Grape";
         
  }
     else if (symbols[k] == 3) {
         logo[j] = "Orange";
         
  }
     else if (symbols[k] == 4) {
         logo[j] = "Lemon";
         
  }
  System.out.println(logo[j] + " ");
     }
```

System.out.println("symbol #: " + symbols[0] + " logo: " + logo[0]);
System.out.println("symbol #: " + symbols[1] + " logo: " + logo[1]);
System.out.println("symbol #: " + symbols[2] + " logo: " + logo[2]);`

Answer (score 2):

You should not have a nested loop here. Use just a single loop, accessing elements from both arrays at the same index on each iteration.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
    if (symbols[i] == 0) {
        logo[i] = "Cherry";
    } else if 
       // other checks...
}
```

Since all the possible `symbol` values form a consecutive range, it is simpler to index into an array of all the symbols, avoiding a long chain of `if` statements. (If they were not consecutive, a `Map` can be used instead.)

```java
final String[] allSymbols = {"Cherry", "7", "Grape", "Orange", "Lemon"};
for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
    logo[i] = allSymbols[symbols[i]];
}
```

Comment: I appreciate this! As I posted this question I actually realized this method and how much simpler it is... I was just being extremely stubborn and was trying to make my original idea work. Thank you though!!

Comment: @Elijah-AmirHodges Happy to help. If you want to stick to your original method with the chain of `if`s, then the first part of my answer addresses that (i.e. use a single loop and use the same index to access both arrays).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second inner for loop. You can also use a enhanced switch:

```
for (int k = 0; k < symbols.length; ++k) {
  switch (symbols[k]) {
    case 0 -> logo[k] = "Cherry";
    case 1 -> logo[k] = "7";
    case 2 -> logo[k] = "Grape";
    case 3 -> logo[k] = "Orange";
    case 4 -> logo[k] = "Lemon";
  }
}
```